# Angular template within template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, single-page-application, partials

Lets see if I can describe my setup here...

I'm designing an angular app, as of now everything is all one page. Basically, when the user clicks a button, the controller sets which

```
"<ng-include>"
```

tag is visible. So my html looks something like this.

```
<html ng-app= "myApp">
    <head>
        <!-- header stuff -->
        <!-- all the includes and everything -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <!-- page nav bar, its a lot of html but it works -->
        </div>

        <!-- content area -->
        <div ng-show= "showHome">
            <ng-include= "home.html">
        </div>
        <div ng-show= "showProfile">
            <ng-include= "profile.html">
        </div>
        <!-- etc... -->

    </body>
</html>
```

And then in my controller, I'm just setting the proper "showHome", "showProfile", etc... as appropriate. My question is, this seems like a terrible way to scale, and this is my first attempt at an app like this.

So to reiterate. I want to give the user the appearance of a single page app, while swapping in html templates. Any ideas? Multiple pages would be ok, but I want to keep the same navbar at the top of every page.

Comment: why don't you use UI routing. http://joelhooks.com/blog/2013/07/22/the-basics-of-using-ui-router-with-angularjs/

Comment: go to tutorial on docs site and see how `ng-view` works along with `$routeProvider`

Comment: Have a look at this: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07

Comment: thanks guys. This is a good first step

Comment: To everyone, I should mention that this app uses a flask/jinja backend, although I'm not sure the difference that makes.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) instead.

It is a popular alternative for ngRoute and supports nested templates really well.

Comment: `ui-router` has a lot of great features and functionality currently lacking in `ngRoute`